# Troubleshooting intermittantly long 'page loading' problem

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Working off IIS 7 with an asp.net mvc app.

Most page accesses are lightening quick. Sometimes the browser reports 'page loading' for an exceptionally long time. We are still in the development/testing mode so it's not a network/bandwidth issue. Happens in both IE and FF. No explicit error conditions in the server logs.

If i could reproduce it i could run firebug/fiddler to give more info. As it is, it's a little too infrequent to simply leave both those running hoping for the condition to fire - unless/until that's the only option to get better info.

I have a hunch this is client-side jquery/ajax related but only a hunch - don't have enough background in either jQuery or MVC to really know what can go wrong.

Any initial troubleshooting suggestions welcome.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a memory or connection leak perhaps (perhaps extensive gc occuring), is the site database driven and what or-mapper if any is used? Basically, developers need to debug it if it's not obviously a system issue. Using a DataContext for instance has many coding gotchas that can generate this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Not to ask the blatantly obvious but are you sure it's not the app pool building?  Does it only happen right after a rollout of code?  Do you see app pool resets right around the time you are seeing this?

Page Loading for a while is a typical response from an application pool starting up.

Comment: Alas, no. Though it's occurred to me that perhaps not all the various DLLs that comprise the app might not all pool at the very outset - that maybe some 'things' or elements might be deferred until they are literally accessed. Seems not very likely - but still...i've explicitly reloaded a page (a page dependent on db interaction so not something that would be cached) that had been stuck and have _always_ found it to re-load very quick.

Answer (score 0):

> If i could reproduce it i could run firebug/fiddler to give more info.

Since you can not reproduce yet, consider monitoring it *periodically* with iMacros or Selenium (or hosted at AlertFox).

Maybe you can see a pattern. I know that this helped us once to identify a tricky issue, we found a 12h pattern and could then match it with our code.